# JS scripts not working for divs loaded with jQuery's .load()

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, materialize, jquery-load

So I have div with some `php` inside. It is executing some records from sql database.

```
<div id="records">
  <?php
  list_query(select_records()); // some php returning divs
  ?>
</div>
```

I'm using materialize's [collapsible](https://materializecss.com/collapsible.html) for viewing more info of that record. When you click on that one line (record), it expanses just like in materialize's examples.

And I have html select above, where you can choose from which date you wanna return those records.

```
<form class="ajax" action="action/timeSort.php" method="post">
  <select name="timeSort" class="timeSortSelect">
    <option value="1">Last 24 hours</option>
    <option value="7">Last 7 days </option>
    <option value="30">Last 30 days</option>
    <option value="365">Last 365 days</option>
    <option value="all" selected>Everything</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

Than I have jquery ajax called, when you choose any option. It will send post to php file and creates php `$_SESSION` with timestamp in it, if ajax is successful this function is called:

```
$('#records').load(document.URL +  ' #records');
```

And in that php `list_query()` function, it reads that `$_SESSION` and sort it from that time.

**Problem here:**
But the problem is, scripts (click events, on events, just anything) for those newly returned records, which were loaded with jQuery's `.load()` function doesn't work. `on('event')` doesn't work, `click()` doesn't work, custom materialize initializations doesn't work. Not even `delegate` events.

**I tried:**
1) Putting new `script src` tag at the end of that `#records` div, so it will load those scripts again - doesn't work

2) Executing those functions after running `.load()` - doesn't work

```
// try #2 example
$('#records').load(document.URL +  ' #records');
$('.collapsible').collapsible(); // doesn't work
$('#records .clickingElement').on('click', function() {/*blah blah*/}) // doesn't work
```

**Possible solutions, which I don't want to do (yet):**
1) Get somehow info about those records from that php action file and append it via jQuery, than `delegate` events or my try #1 would work. But it's not nice thing to do, but I'll try.

2) Refreshing whole site. Pfff, I'm better than that and nobody likes force refreshes.

**Main question:** Is there a jQuery solution for it, like some special events? Or do you have an better idea how to achieve the same sorting, but with a better way?

If you don't understand something or want more code, feel free to comment about it. Thanks for your help.

**Edit:** Image example of how it looks executed and working (it expands like this when you click on it)

[image: image example]

Comment: you need to (re-) set the event listeners _after_ the new items got loaded/inserted to the dom; in the success-callback of `load()`, right after you add them to the dom.

Comment: @Jeff do you mean my try #2?

Comment: kind of. It needs to be in the _callback function_: `$('#records').load(document.URL +  ' #records', function() { $('.collapsible').collapsible(); });`

Comment: `load()` is an asynchronous function. As you have it now `collapsible()` will start before `load()` has finished.

Comment: @Jeff well, I'm testing what you told and it is working pretty well. But when I'm calling those functions again, it can execute twice (maybe not on those dynamic elements). I can unbind click events and than call that load function with click events (this will prevent double or more executing), but is it efficient?

Comment: place all events in $(document).ready(function(){
// here
});
and also try 
$(document).on('click', '#records .clickingElement', function() {/*blah blah*/}) // should work

Comment: And @Jeff, thank you so much for that function inside .load(), it helped me a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set your on click function:

```
$('#records .clickingElement').on('click', function() {/*blah blah*/}) // doesn't work
```

To this:

```
$(document).on('click', '#records .clickingElement', function() {
    /*blah blah*/
});
```

This makes sure that the event trigger traverses through the entire dom to see if the #records or .clickingElement exist. Instead of it only binding to those elements on load. If that makes any sense.

This has a good answer for you: [Click event doesn't work on dynamically generated elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6658752/click-event-doesnt-work-on-dynamically-generated-elements#answer-6658774)

Comment: And even more reference material can be found [here](http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events)

Comment: Note that for performance issues, you should ideally bind to the closest non-dynamic element. Bind to `$(document)` only if there is no better choice.

Comment: @Jeto Agreed ;)

Comment: Well that is delegate event and as I already wrote in "Problem here", it doesn't work for some reason.

Comment: Is the data being returned with the correct class and id associated with it?

Comment: Yes it is. Just the same, I'm calling the same php function just like at the first load.

Comment: Omg, I'm dumb, yes it works, gooood, I tried that before. It didn't work, because materialize function needs to be called, it opens dropdown.